# Task fanout - how to bulk add Tasks to the Queue - more than 5

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I am using a task (queueing-task) to queue multiple others tasks — fanout. When I try to use [Queue.add](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/queues.html#Queue_add) with task argument being a list of [Task](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks.html) instances with more than 5 element's and in transaction…  I get this error.

```
JointException: taskqueue.DatastoreError caused by: 
    <class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_errors.BadRequestError'> 
    Too many messages, maximum allowed 5
```

Is there another way to queue more than 5 tasks in a transaction?

Or...

Maybe I don't need a transaction, cause:

1. I don't care if any of those tasks get queued twice anyway, and
2. if queueing will fail for any of them, then the whole queueing-task will be re run.

So tell me how do I queue more than 5 tasks in a transaction or tell me to not use transaction cause I don't really need one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution *close* to solving your problem is to add **one transactional task** that fans-out the remaining tasks.  Just add the one fan-out task in your existing transaction.

Unless there is a business logic reason to do so, do not re-run a task that has already run.  Preventing tasks from being re-inserted (i.e. duplicated) is straightforward and saves resources.  Your fan-out task will basically look like:

```
class FanOutTask(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    name = self.request.get('name')
    params = deserialize(self.request.get('params'))

    try:
      task_params = params.get('stuff')
      taskqueue.add(url='/worker/1', name=name + '-1', params=task_params)
    except TaskAlreadyExistsError:
      pass

    try:
      task_params = params.get('more')
      taskqueue.add(url='/worker/2', name=name + '-2', params=task_params)
    except TaskAlreadyExistsError:
      pass
```

Adding the fan-out task transactionally ensures it is enqueued.  Errors resulting from the task already being run get caught and ignored, other errors cause the fan-out task to re-run.  With this pattern you can insert many sub-tasks pretty easily.